# How to enable PHP mail() function in dokku on DigitalOcean

Tags: php, sendmail, digital-ocean, dokku

I have deployed a PHP website with Dokku on DigitalOcean. It is a very simple website that has a contact form in it. However, the form cannot be sent because apparently PHP `mail()` function does not work.

I have installed `sendmail` on the server machine and I am able to send email with `sendmail` on command line. I have followed the instructions here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/do-I-need-to-configure-anything-to-use-php-mail-function-on-fresh-lamp-install

but I keep getting this error:

> -bash: export:`/usr/sbin/sendmail:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games': not a valid identifier

Following the third answer here to the same question as mine (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/php-mail-function-enable); I have installed `postfix` and I tried to change the `php.ini` file (which was located in a weird path like /etc/php5/cli/) on the server. I am not sure at all if that `php.ini` file is what dokku uses while compiling the app even.

I cannot find any other documentation on this issue and I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: don't use php's mail(). it's mickey-mouse garbage. use a proper mailing package like phpmailer or swiftmailer.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. PHPMailer does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the wise advice from @MarcB on the comments **do use a proper mail client like phpMailer or SwiftMailer** on the specifics of your problem you can easy debug your php values by running **`phpinfo()`**.

Specifically look for:
- sendmail_path

You can also fine tune some aspects of it by looking into:
- mail.add_x_header
- mail.force_extra_parameters
- mail.log
- sendmail_from

As per the error described check the file `~/.bashrc` and clean up whatever you've put there. It looks as though you've prexied `PATH` in the variable form as `$PATH`.

It should have something like `export PATH=...`